# nginx inside a docker container doesn't add access-control-allow-origin header as per the conf file

Tags: docker, elastic-stack, nginx-location

tl;dr - how to add a specific header in nginx response explicitly when running nginx inside a docker container?

I have deployed ELK stack inside a docker container on a RHEL 7.1 using sebp/elk:latest image. I also want to render my own scatterplots that I have developed, apart from Kibana graphs. I am rendering those pages through a separate nginx webserver I install and run in the same docker image. This is because Kibana 4 (in the sebp image) doesn't give a freedom to choose another web server like Kibana 3, and I can't possibly edit URLs/ Pages rendered by Kibana 4 as it is using its own inbuilt non-nginx webserver as far as I could understood. Now, the issue is, when I deploy my scatterplts to nginx root location and retrieve from browser, I get below error.

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:///_search?size=500&. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://IP-of-my-server' is therefore not allowed access.**

I had faced this issue while running ELK without docker but this link has helped me - http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Now it doesn't seem to work, I am pushing the conf from my host to container while building the docker image and when a container is spun up from the image I could login and see nginx is running and my nginx.conf is being used but when I analyse actual response, no such header is added to the response even though it should be as I have added it in nginx.

Nginx 1.4 is being used. There is no issue of port mapping and I am not running any nginx on the host, as some of you might suspect if those pages are really being rendered by nginx of the container or the host.

Please help if you have faced this issue and resolved. Does the header gets added into response if you are running webserver from inside the container or there is bug in docker or add_header is not supported in my nginx version?

When I open a session of chrome with disabled web security, I get my scatterplots in chrome perfectly.

**chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security**

So scatterplot code or something else definitely doesn't have any issue. It's only with the header being absent in the response even though I explicitely try to add it through conf/

Thanks in advance, sorry for a bit long post.

Comment: Can you paste your nginx config please.

Comment: i would suggest you get inside the container and debug this ... docker exec -it containerName bash ... is everything as expected inside the container? any warnings when stating / restarting NGINX? is the version of NGINX inside the container as expected? is NGINX using the right conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized issue was with elasticsearch response and not in nginx conf. If you see carefully that header is not presence in response from :9200, so there is a module named "http" and you can edit its properties in elasticsearch.yml file.

Below link helped, had to allow that header through its APIs.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html